# Add a new line in String at nearest space every 100 characters

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am coding the back end of a production system for my gelato manufacturing company and I haven't work with Javascript since Freshman year of college. Basically, myString is a list of ingredients in a Google Sheet that is imported from our ordering system. It is usually very long and needs to be split for the label software. I need all of myString to stay in one cell, but have a new line (or CTRL enter) every 100 characters, but it has to be at a space. Here is what I have but it does not work past the first occurrence.

```
function insertNewLine(myString) {
    var ret = [];
    var i;
    var len;
    var n = 100;
    var currentString = myString.substr(i,n);
    var character = String.fromCharCode(10);

    for(i = 0, len = myString.length; i < len; i += 100) {

    var before = currentString.lastIndexOf(' ', n);
          n = before;

      ret.push(currentString + character);
      currentString = myString.substr(n, n+100);
      n=100;      
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't know about javascript, but java returns `-1` if `lastIndexOf` can't find what you're looking for, check that.

Comment: the first space after 100, before 100, or just the closest in either direction?

Answer (score 1):

Approach that splits into words array first and iterates that array to build new string

```js
var str = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."

var lineBreak = '\n',
  words = str.split(' '),
  newStr = words.shift(),
  charCount = newStr.length;

words.forEach(function(word, i) {
  charCount += word.length + 1;
  if (charCount <= 100) {
    newStr += ' ';
  } else {
    newStr += lineBreak;
    charCount = word.length
  }
  newStr += word;
});
// demo only to show line lengths
var lines= newStr.split(lineBreak).map(function(str){
   return str.length
})
document.getElementById('res').value = newStr;
document.getElementById('lengths').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(lines);
```

```html
<h3>line lengths</h3>
<pre id="lengths"></pre>
<h4>new Text</h4>
<textarea id="res" style="width:100%; height:300px"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a little bit of refactoring and added some tests to ensure it worked correctly.

Here's the JSBin: http://jsbin.com/xoheqey/1/edit?js,console

And here's the updated version:

```
function insertNewLine(myString) {
    var output = myString;
    var i;
    var len = myString.length;
    var n = 100;
    var newLine = String.fromCharCode(10);

    // Do not add new line if less than 100 characters long.
    if ( len < 100 ) {
      return myString;
    }

    for( i = 0; i < len; i += 100) {
      // if over hundred characters left
      if ( (len - i) >= n ) {
        var lastHundrethSpace = output.lastIndexOf(' ', n+i);
        output = output.splice(lastHundrethSpace, 0, newLine);
      }
    }
    return output;
}
```

That should work, let me know if there's an issue!

Comment: Note: this does require a polyfill for the `String.prototype.splice()` method to work (it is included in the JSBin). Also if you want to remove the last space, just change the `0` to a `1` in the splice method, so it becomes: `output = output.splice(lastHundrethSpace, 1, newLine);`

Comment: Run it for 200 characters without any space. Failed!